# How to install ubuntu 17.04 alongside Debian Wheezy

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, 17.04, debian

I have a Debian Wheezy workstation, and I'd like to install Ubuntu 17.04 alongside Debian.

I know it's possible; however, I'm a bit unsure about how to correctly edit my partition table so I won't brake the Debian instalation (I'd like to keep Debian because I'm comfortable working on it... I have most of my work tools up and running already, and it would take me some time to install everything on Ubuntu).

So, my specific question is: *How to properly install Ubuntu 17.04 alongside my Debian instalation?*

The topics I'd like to know about are:

1. How to properly edit my partitions? 
   Some information:

   - I have a single hard drive, 1.3 TB
   - I have 750 GB of free space
   - The main partition is `ext4`
2. Will GRUB automatically recognize both systems, so I can freely choose which one I want to boot?
3. Will I be able to mount the Debian partition on Ubuntu to access my files?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm feeling a bit dumb right now: Ubuntu Installer takes care of everything: the installer detects the Debian installation and simply asks how much space should Ubuntu take. 
Grub is configured automatically, so there's nothing left but to wait for the installation to finish and boot the system.

I thought I'd have to manually edit the partition table but it was not necessary.

Comment: I have done the same but with 16.04, but I keep on gettingg the Debian grub2 screen as if nothing had happened.